# How do I delete the contents of a form when switching between states?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a email form in a custom component that is put in the main application when switching to the email state. When someone searches something it will switch back to the search state. But when the person eventually goes back to the email state the contents of the form is still there.

I tried doing a creationComplete and running a function that makes the fields have no text such as email.text = ""; but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of creating a bindable class instance, and upon state change, create a new instance of the class?